# CollapsingToolbarLayout without onTouch?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to understand how some view works. I start reading the source code of CollapsingToolbarLayout. But i am confused, there is not onTouch function in it whereas we need to touch our screen to expand/collapse the view.

So how CollapsingToolbarLayout can be collapsed/expanded with our finger but there's no onTouch method overrided?

Can somebody explain to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because onTouch isn't the only way to interact with Views.

For `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, you first need to understand that it is designed to be used as a child of `AppBarLayout`.

`AppBarLayout` is pretty much a vertical `LinearLayout` that's used to implement lots of features that belong to Material Design, including the scrolling features. In other words, this layout is what handles the scrolling for the child View.

In the source of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, look at the `onAttachedToWindow()` method. Inside this method, you'll see that if the parent of this toolbar is an `AppBarLayout`, then it'll set a custom-defined `OffsetUpdateListener` into it's parent's `addOnOffsetChangedListener()` method. Look further down the source to see the definition of it's `OffsetUpdateListener`.

What this does is `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is telling it's parent `(AppBarLayout)` to tell itself if there are any changes to the 'offset' which is the scrolling.

So there's no need for `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to have an 'OnTouch' override, because it doesn't handle the touches or scrolling. It simply allows it's parent to handle the scrolling while it just tells the parent to let it know when it should react, in other words... when it should collapse or expand.

Answer (score 1):

they use OnOffsetChangedListener which is an interface definition for a callback to be invoked when an AppBarLayout's vertical offset changes.

onOffsetChanged Called when the AppBarLayout's layout offset has been changed. This allows child views to implement custom behavior based on the offset (for instance pinning a view at a certain y value).

here is the reference [OnOffsetChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is not a `View` but `ViewGroup`. It inherits from `FrameLayout` and acts as container for `AppBarLayout` when some of view needed to be **collapsed/expanded** based on **app bar's scrolling behavior**.

So, it's a wrapper for `Toolbar` which implements a collapsing app bar. It is designed to be used as a direct child of a `AppBarLayout`.

---

Now for your question :

"**So how `CollapsingToolbarLayout` can be collapsed/expanded with our finger but there's no `onTouch` method overrided?**"

Answer is simple, it doesn't. It's the `AppBarLayout` itself which intercepts touch event based on **OffsetChange listener** and passes callbacks to it's descendants. `CollapsingToolbarLayout` has ability to animate toolbar title (collapse/expand) and some other stuffs like scriming background, pinning title etc. so, basically it responds to `AppBarLayout`'s **OffsetChange listener** when callbacks received.

Check out [official reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout) for more details.